# Multiple RelativeSizeSpan on same line

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, spannablestring

I'm trying to use two RelativeSizeSpan next to each other, but a big gap appears in between. See what I want to achieve and what I'm getting.

[image: My goal] [image: what I get]

This is how I'm building the Spanned instance

```
    String formattedValue = "25%";
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(formattedValue);
    ssb.append("\n");
    ssb.append(otherValue);

    int firstSpanEnd = formattedValue.length();
    ssb.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 0, firstSpanEnd-1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ssb.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.3f), firstSpanEnd, firstSpanEnd+1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

And this is how I'm drawing it

```
  float maxTextWidth = getPaintCenterText().measureText(mText, 0, mText.length());

  TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint(getPaintCenterText());

  mCenterTextLayout = new StaticLayout(mText, textPaint, (int) maxTextWidth, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 0.85f, 0, false);

  c.save();

  float centerY = center.y - totalheight;

  c.translate(center.x, centerY);

  mCenterTextLayout.draw(c);

  c.restore();
```

If I remove the second RelativeSizeSpan the gap is smaller, but it's still there.

Also, I've tried several Spanned flags, but none seem to have any effect.

Edit: mText field of my SpannableStringBuilder

```
[0] = '2' 48
[1] = '5' 46
[2] = '%' 48
[3] = '\n' 10
[4] = 'E' 69
[5] = 'x' 120
[6] = 'e' 101
[7] = 'r' 114
[8] = 'c' 99
[9] = 'i' 105
[10] = 's' 115
[11] = 'e' 101
[12] = ' ' 32
[13] = 'd' 100
[14] = 'a' 97
[15] = 'y' 121
[16] = 's' 115
[17] = '\u0000' 0
[18] = '\u0000' 0
[19] = '\u0000' 0
[20] = '\u0000' 0
[21] = '\u0000' 0
[22] = '\u0000' 0
```

Comment: I get this using your code: [Link](http://postimg.org/image/5yvfj4etp/). The only change I made was `ssb.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.3f), firstSpanEnd-1, firstSpanEnd, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);` which was probably a typo. Using the default typeface with text size 30sp.

Comment: thanks @Vikram, I'll look into it as soon as I can, which will be on monday

Comment: That didn't work. As soon as I add a RelativeSizeSpan or AbsoluteSizeSpan, a big gap appears (Nexus 4 emulator and One Plus One, both on 4.4). Thanks for trying tho

Comment: I didn't really change anything. Your code would have thrown some exception relating to index being out of bounds: `firstSpanEnd+1` is beyond your string's length. To me, it looks like there's a space character between `25` and `%`. You could print the unicode value of each character and confirm if that's the case.

Comment: My string is "25%\nOtherValue". firstSpanEnd should be 3, hence it's not out of bounds, right? I can see unicode characters at the end of the SpannableStringBuilder, but none where the gap appears. I've edited my question, comments don't style nicely

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. The first three values look wrong though. And `firstSpanEnd` cannot be 3. The start index is included in the span. So, we start at `0`. The end index is _not_ included in the span - end index should be one past. Your indices are the first span should be: [0,2); for the second - [2,3). Currently your indices are [0,2) & [3,4). This still doesn't explain the spacing problem.

Comment: My guess is that the problem lies more on the drawing side than on the Span part. For now I'm giving up, I've spent way too much time on a tiny detail. Thanks a lot for your dedication!

Comment: No problem. See if displaying the spannable string in a textview changes anything. On my end, I got similar results using StaticLayout & TextView.

Comment: The SpannableString works just fine when using it on a TextView, so the problem must be on how I draw it. I'm updating the question with the full drawing code.

Comment: I was finally able to reproduce the spacing issue. What properties do you set on the return value of `getPaintCenterText()`? If its `setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER)`, remove it. Instead, use `Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER` in place of `Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL` when creating the `StaticLayout`.

Comment: wow, that did the trick, so grateful! Please answer the question so that I can award the bounty. Also, did you just guess or is there a reason for that behaviour? I'm yet to find a nice reference for java canvas.

Comment: `Also, did you just guess or is there a reason for that behaviour?` Kind of a guess. From what I know, setting `Paint.Align.CENTER` on `TextPaint` will affect the placing of a text character inside its bounding rect. The RelativeSizeSpan will exaggerate this. So, I guessed that `Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER` would be more appropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER)` on `TextPaint` might be interfering with your spans.

Instead, use `Layout.Alignment.CENTER` on the `StaticLayout` which should center the text as a whole.

```
mCenterTextLayout = new StaticLayout(mText, textPaint, (int) maxTextWidth, 
                          Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 0.85f, 0, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this code this is giving the proper output as per your requirement
[image]

```
editText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.setTextSize(40);
        SpannableString span1 = new SpannableString("25%");
        SpannableString span2 = new SpannableString("25%");

        span1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.3f),  2, 3, 0);
        span1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f),  0, 2, 0);

        span2.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.3f),  2, 3, 0);
        span2.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f),  0, 2, 0);

        editText.setText(TextUtils.concat(span1," " ,span2));
```

Comment: thanks @Fahim, but it turns out it had to do with the Paint used to draw the StaticLayout

Answer (score 0):

firstSpanEnd has a value of 3 in your example.

The first RelativeSizeSpan would then be applied to the characters [0, 2] -> 25.

The second RelativeSizeSpan would be applied to the characters [3, 4] which is the \n not the % character.

```
ssb.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 0, firstSpanEnd-1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
ssb.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.3f), firstSpanEnd-1, firstSpanEnd, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

should fix the issue but I guess there's an underlying layout bug that causes the space (the \n probably) showing before the %.

Comment: If `firstSpanEnd` is still `3`, your second span is applied on `\n`. `...  there's an underlying layout bug that causes the space (the \n probably) showing before the %`. Wouldn't `%` be on the next line then?

Comment: You're right. For some reason I copied the original code instead of the correct one (just fixed). I haven't tested this but since you weren't able to reproduce it with the correct code (and the OP still has the issue with the corrected code) this might be related to certain Android versions or manufacturer implementations. If the \n causes the spacing instead of a just breaking the line then the % could still be on the same line.

Comment: The SpannableString works just fine when using it on a TextView, so the problem must be on how I draw it. I'm updating the question with the full drawing code.