# How to set gravity center of SpannableStringBuilder?

Tags: android, text, spannable

I'm using two different fonts in one TextView: first is SVG font , second TTF font.

To set icon with text to TextView I'm using this:

```
        String icon =getContext().getString(iconId);//"&#xF119;"
        String text = getResources().getString(labelId);//"AnyText"

        int iconLength = icon.length();
        String fulltext = icon + " " + text;
        SpannableStringBuilder spLabelWithIcon = new SpannableStringBuilder(fulltext);
        spLabelWithIcon.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan(TypefaceManager.ICONS.getTypeface()),
                0, iconLength, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

        spLabelWithIcon.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan(TypefaceManager.GOTHAM_BOOK.getTypeface()),
                iconLength, fulltext.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

myTextView.setText(spLabelWithIcon);
```

Result: **the icon is not on vertical center of the line(or maybe text is not on vertical center):**

[image]

Comment: found answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36964034/how-to-make-relativesizespan-align-to-top